# Swift: cannot subscript a value of type aka 'Array<Character>'

Tags: swift, nsstring, nsarray

I'm trying to access to one character in string but I'm getting the following error:

```
error: cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<_Element>' (aka 'Array<Character>')
        finalString = characters [ 5 ]
```

Here is my code:

// my string:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
```

// I'm converting the string into array of characters:

```
let characters = Array(str.characters)
```

// String where I want to transfer the character:

```
var finalString:String

finalString = characters [ 5 ]
```

But in the last line of code is where I get the error. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or a way around this error.

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of Characters, you need to turn that back into a string to get what you want. Try this:

```
// my string:
var str = "Hello, playground"

// I'm converting the string into array of characters:
let characters = Array(str.characters)

// String where I want to transfer the character:
var finalString = String(characters[ 5 ])
```